# jquery multilevel select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

i have problem with my multilevel dependent select lists, i have six select lists dependent on each other and i have write a code to create dynamic lists using jquery. selects named as district, tehsil, project, center, school and user. it is working fine when i choose all options in a sequence, ***district-> tehsil-> project -> center -> school -> user***, and when i change sequence at any level like ***district -> tehsil -> district( here district is parent of tehsil***) after clicking on parent child tehsil not refreshed, and this problem exist in all hierarchy.... this jquery code calls 6 controller and models. those are not include here due to length of question. what should i do ?
this is my jquery code

```
$('#districts_id,#tehsils_id,#projects_id,#centers_id,#schools_id').on('change', function() {

                    //alert($("#districts_id option:selected").attr("title"));
                    //var parameters = {};
                    var parameters;
                    var url;

                    if($('#schools_id').val())
                    {
                        $("#users_id").removeAttr('disabled');
                        //parameters = JSON.stringify({schools_centers_id:$('#centers_id').val()});
                        parameters = {"users_schools_id": $('#schools_id').val(), users_gender: $('#gender').val()};
                        url = "<?php echo base_url();?>/BtaAdministratorUnionMembers/get_teachers_users_by_school_id";
                    }
                    else if($('#centers_id').val())
                    {
                        $("#schools_id").removeAttr('disabled');
                        //parameters = JSON.stringify({schools_centers_id:$('#centers_id').val()});
                        parameters = {"schools_centers_id": $('#centers_id').val()};
                        url = "<?php echo base_url();?>/BtaAdministratorUsers/get_schools_by_center_id";
                    }
                    else if($('#projects_id').val())
                    {
                        $("#centers_id").removeAttr('disabled');
                        //parameters = JSON.stringify({centers_probject_id:$('#projects_id').val()});
                        parameters = {"centers_probject_id": $('#projects_id').val()};
                        url = "<?php echo base_url();?>/BtaAdministratorUsers/get_centers_by_project_id";
                    }
                    else if($("#tehsils_id option:selected").attr("title") == 'tehsils_id')//($('#tehsils_id').val())
                    {
                        $("#projects_id").removeAttr('disabled');
                        //parameters = JSON.stringify({projects_tehsil_id:$('#tehsils_id').val()});
                        parameters = {"projects_tehsil_id": $('#tehsils_id').val()};
                        url = "<?php echo base_url();?>/BtaAdministratorUsers/get_projects_by_tehsil_id";
                        //alert(parameters + ' '+ url);
                    }
                    else if($("#districts_id option:selected").attr("title") == 'districts_id')//($('#districts_id').val())
                    {
                        $("#tehsils_id").removeAttr('disabled');
                        //$("#tehsils_id").empty();
                        //parameters = JSON.stringify({tehsils_districts_id:$('#districts_id').val()});
                        parameters = {"tehsils_districts_id": $('#districts_id').val()};
                        url = "<?php echo base_url();?>/BtaAdministratorUsers/get_tehsils_by_districts_id";
                        //alert(parameters + ' '+ url);
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    data:parameters,
                    //contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data){
                    //alert(data);
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                        if($('#schools_id').val())
                        {
                            //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                            $('#users_id').empty();
                            $('#users_id').append("<option value=''>Select Teacher....</option>");
                            $.each(data,function(key,value){
                                $('#users_id').append('<option value="'+value.users_id+'">'+value.users_firstname_users_lastname+'</option>');
                                });
                        }
                        else if($('#centers_id').val())
                        {
                            //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                            $('#schools_id').empty();
                            $('#schools_id').append("<option value=''>Select School....</option>");
                            $.each(data,function(key,value){
                                $('#schools_id').append('<option value="'+value.schools_id+'">'+value.schools_name+'</option>');
                                });
                        }
                        else if($('#projects_id').val())
                        {
                            //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                            $('#centers_id').empty();
                            $('#centers_id').append("<option value=''>Select Center....</option>");
                            $.each(data,function(key,value){
                                $('#centers_id').append('<option value="'+value.centers_id+'">'+value.centers_schoolName+'</option>');
                                });
                        }
                        else if($("#tehsils_id option:selected").attr("title") == 'tehsils_id')//($('#tehsils_id').val())
                        {
                            //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                            $('#projects_id').empty();
                            $('#projects_id').append("<option value=''>Select Project....</option>");
                            $.each(data,function(key,value){
                                $('#projects_id').append('<option value="'+value.projects_id+'">'+value.projects_name+'</option>');
                                }); 
                        }
                        else if($("#districts_id option:selected").attr("title") == 'districts_id')//($('#districts_id').val())
                        {
                            //clearDropDown($('select'), 5);
                            $('#tehsils_id').empty();
                            $('#tehsils_id').append("<option value='' title=tehsils_id>Select Tehsils....</option>");
                            $.each(data,function(key,value){
                                $('#tehsils_id').append('<option value="'+value.tehsils_id+'" title=tehsils_id>'+value.tehsils_name+'</option>');
                                });
                        }
                    },
                error: function(data){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    //console.log(data);
    }
                    });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In each level you have to remove all next options when a top level option is changed and the set the next level again e.g in school level:

```
$('#schools_id').nextAll("select").each(function(){
   $(this).find('option').remove();
})
// Then set again the next level
```

I used `nextAll` assuming that selects are siblings. elsewhere you have to use propper selector

Answer (score 0):

With all of your if else statements organized from the most specific to least specific, fiddling with a parent input triggers the event handler but is caught by the else statement for its child.

Use separate event handlers for all six inputs based on the one you are interacting with rather than checking for values alone, and your logic will work morelike you planned.

You'll even be able to more easily handle the case where the user is jumping back a few levels and you should reset/disable a few selects.